# Wiring diagram/configuration for 8 outlets with 1 GFCI

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

I am installing a new circuit using a 20 amp breaker with 20 amp outlets and 1 GFCI. Should the GFCI be the first outlet from breaker panel? How do I wire this project?

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not the GFCI is the first as far as proximity from the panel, it would have to be the first if you want it to protect the other receptacles. However, since you're going the route of covering so many receptacles. I'd recommend just getting a GFCI breaker to cover the whole line.

Do you want to have all of the receptacles GFCI covered? You would follow this wiring diagram if so (and continue it on like normal to add in all the rest):

[image: GFCI covering outlets]

However, with a GFCI breaker you would just wire all standard receptacles like normal and add the breaker in the panel:

[image: With GFCI breaker]

If you want the GFCI to only cover itself, then you would connect it as such and then again connect the rest as usual:

[image: GFCI explained]

**(NOTE: For this last image, do know that you need to pigtail off of the receptacle screws in the left side setup. Do NOT connect two wires to a single terminal.)**